# Python: How to make map() skip data types that can't be transformed?

Tags: python, list

```
abc = ["1","2","3","4","5","A"]

print (list(map(int, la)))
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'

I tried something with try-except, didn't work.

Expected output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,"A"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a custom function which does the conversion:

```py
abc = ["1","2","3","4","5","A"]

def intOrNot(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except:
        return value

print (list(map(intOrNot, abc)))
```

Output as requested.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do `except: return value` and skip the `pass`?

Answer (score 1):

Another way not using the map.

```
abc = ["1","2","3","4","5","A"]

new = []

for elem in abc:
    try:
        converted = int(elem)
    except:
        converted = elem
    new.append(converted)
```

As they say: keep it simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

For (positive) integer numbers, you could just use a list comprehension with a ternary and `str.isdigit`:

```
abc = ["1","2","3","4","5","A"]
print([int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in abc])
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'A']
```

For negative integers or float, a `regex` may work:

```
import re
abc = ["1","2","3","-4","5","A"]
print([int(x) if re.match("-?\d+", x) else x for x in abc])
# [1, 2, 3, -4, 5, 'A']
```

If you want or have to rely on `try/except` instead, you might create a wrapper function for that:

```
def tryit(f):
    def _f(*args):
        try:
            return f(*args)
        except:
            return args[0]
    return _f

print(list(map(tryit(int), abc)))
# [1, 2, 3, -4, 5, 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def intOrNot(number):
    if number.isdigit():
        return int(number)
    
abc =["1",'a']

print(list(map(intOrNot, abc)))
```

Comment: This returns `[1, None]` instead of expected `[1, 'a']`

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.